# How can I find html elements base on wfd-id using selenium?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a website that use wfd-id to identify html elements. Since most of the html elements in this website use wfd-id, it will make my program much faster if I can use findelement with wfd-id. I have tried using driver.FindelementsbyId, but it didn't work. I also tried to look print out attribute with "wfd-id", it also didn't print out anything.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

I actually can use **FindElementsbyTag** and then loop through the collection to look for the html text, but I noticed that each element has a unique wfd-id so it might be better if I can find element by wfd-id instead.

Comment: Please share your code. Include relevant html using snippet tool available via [edit].

Answer (score 1):

You can use css and form your selector such as `tag[wfd-id='foo']`

For example. If you have an element `<div wfd-id="username">`, you could select it using:

```
"div[wfd-id='username']"
```

Comment: I have tried using driver.FindElementByCss("button[wfd-id='821']").Click, but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: That should work assuming it's the right wfd-id. The one in your picture is 905. Make sure the element is present before you try to find it. You could also try it in the browser console `document.querySelector("button[wfd-id='905']")`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say until you provide HTML and your existing code.

You can use an attribute CSS selector to match on the attribute `wfd-id`  and apply via `.FindElementsByCss` to return the collection of `WebElements`. You then loop and access individual elements content using `.Text` property.

```
Dim elems As WebElements, elem As WebElement
Set elems = bot.FindElementsByCss("[wfd-id]")
For Each elem In elems
    Debug.Print elem.Text
Next
```

Comment: Did you try this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that its id is unique then you can use xpath in findelement;

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@wdf-id='905']"))
```